# I was wondering how to test the contracts that draw functions from interfaces in uniswap v3 periphery

Tags: solidity, uniswap, hardhat

It seems like there is one large contract inheriting interfaces but the code is written like there is a contract instance out there? I don't really understand. Theoretically it should work however a contract I tested gave an error stating that the contract cannot call a function from a non-contract account?

```
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol';

contract MyContract {
  ISwapRouter router;

  function doSomethingWithSwapRouter() {
    // router.exactInput(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `router` is just instanciatiated but has not been initialized. If you are going to call `doSomethingWithSwapRouter` you must first make router an instance of a ISwapRouter deployed contract, if you are forking mainnet to test you can do:

```
router = ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);
```

Where `0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564` is the address of the deployed contract on the network you are using.

Comment: So I'm assuming something like ISwapRouter router = ISwapRouter(address(...)); works

Comment: But if that's the case I still get the same error? The address is the correct address so that's not the issue. And mainnet has been forked using hardhat. Also, if I were to call a parameter that is only present on the interface but not the contract, how would I go about doing that? Especially if the function I want to call requires the data to be in that format?

Comment: There is also something that I'm not too clear about and that is when I was playing around with the staking part of uniswap v3, I had some issues getting the data correctly, as in here: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/periphery/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager  In Mint Params, to call mint I need the data to be in the Mint Params struct format, however, I can't call an interface and the inherited contract doesn't have that struct. Not sure how to test it out. Sorry for the late reply and thanks a lot.